# How do I change the position of a Google Maps marker?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code for a map that I'm working on and I'd like to see if I can put custom markers throughout.  The problem is that I can't seem to get the first marker to change position no matter if I input latitude and longitude.  Perhaps I'm entering the information incorrectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>UmApp</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=key"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.160531, -73.256303);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: 41.159317, -73.257443,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.159317, -73.257443);
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot make comments, so I'll answer your comment question here:

As Kostrzak said, you would need to write

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.159317, -73.257443),
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

(Careful with the semicolon instead of the comma. Although it should work anyway, it may throw a bunch of errors on some IDEs).

The position inside the Marker object is expecting coordinates, but not in any form. It needs to have those coordinates given in a specific way: As a LatLng object. Because of this, you need to set those coordinates using the Google JavaScript library, which creates an object with your specified coordinates:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.159317, -73.257443)
```

Here you have SET the position of the marker. If you want to change it, you just need to set

`marker.position = new google.maps.LatLng({newLat}, {newLng});`

If you opened the console, you'd see a bunch of errors thrown by the position line: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ". Console logs are pretty helpful most of the times, so use them!

Comment: So to add more markers I would just need to write a new var marker each time?  And to change those generic markers to something specific I would need to reference an icon file or url, correct?  Your suggestion worked beautifully, btw.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, the best approach, if you are going to have more than one marker, is to have a global markers array where you store them, so you have control over them. Otherwise it could be tricky to edit or remove them. You can check how it's done in the "Remove Markers" tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: As for changing marker icons, yes, you just need to add the "icon" parameter to the marker object, with a reference to image url you want to use as an icon. See how they do it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Now I just need to add multiple custom icons throughout the map.  I have a location array that puts the markers at various points throughout the map, but I need to add a custom marker for 3 locations and then a different one for 4 others.  Is there a way that I can reference individual locations in my array to add these custom markers?  I've tried using a couple of examples from Google but no luck.